# Quickly creating JSON entries in an Avro schema

Tags: substitute, macro, repeated-commands

Is there a quicker way to create more entries of form `{ "name": FIELD_NAME, "type": "string" }` from a list of words down below, than recording a macro to process each word and then pasting the result in place?

```
{
  "namespace": "my-space",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Transaction",
  "fields": [
    { "name": "transaction_id", "type": "string" }
  ]
}

# Fields
first_name
last_name
amount
currency
transaction_date
```

I was hoping for an alternative approach where I could use a template string and then use the list of words to create substituted entry for each, so:

```
{ "name": "PLACEHOLDER", "type": "string" } => { "name": "first_name", "type": "string" }
                                               { "name": "last_name", "type": "string" }
                                               ...
```

I'm happy to use the macros, but something along the lines of the above would be more intuitive for me (and hopefully for others, too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using `:substitute`?  First, start with this:

```
{ "name": "\1", "type": "string" }
\(\w\+\)

first_name
last_name
amount
currency
transaction_date
```

Now, on line one, yank to register `a`: `1G^"a$`.  On line two, yank to register `b`: `2G^"b$`.  Then perform the substitute on the appropriate lines:

`:4,8s/<c-r>b/<c-r>a/<cr>`

Note: `<cr>` means the enter key and `<c-r>` means `ctrl+r`

Result:

```
{ "name": "first_name", "type": "string" }
{ "name": "last_name", "type": "string" }
{ "name": "amount", "type": "string" }
{ "name": "currency", "type": "string" }
{ "name": "transaction_date", "type": "string" }
```

You could have also used visual block mode, but this method more easily generalizes to multiple fields; you can use `\1`, `\2` up to `\9`.

Comment: I see you've edited the answer - your previous approach would work if you add a space, e.g. `:1y a<cr>`

Comment: Other than that, I really like your approach here, especially when it allows you to capture multiple fields. Thanks! Let's see if anyone comes up with an alternative, otherwise I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @LordTwaroog indeed forgot the space originally.  With the space, it works, but requires you to remove the `^M` when putting into the command line, which is confusing for a newbie, so I decided `1G^"ay$` is more easily understood.

Comment: I see - I didn't experience that, but I'm assuming that's because I'm on a Mac, not Windows. Or maybe that's a NeoVim thing.